# How to use a variable as jsonpath argument with kubectl

Tags: bash, kubectl, jsonpath

I am using a variable to store jsonpath query as follows:

```
check_deprecating_api() {
    echo "Search for to be soon deprecated API"

    local API_REQUESTS_QUERY='"{range .items[?(@.status.removedInRelease=="1.25")]}'
    API_REQUESTS_QUERY+='{.status.removedInRelease}{"\t"}'
    API_REQUESTS_QUERY+='{.status.requestCount}{"\t"}'
    API_REQUESTS_QUERY+='{.metadata.name}{"\n"}{end}"'
    echo $API_REQUESTS_QUERY
    kubectl get apirequestcounts -o jsonpath=$API_REQUESTS_QUERY
}
```

But I can't.

Tried every answer in https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/503572/how-to-break-a-long-string-into-multiple-lines-assigned-to-a-variable-in-linux-b but still can't make jsonpath use my variable API_REQUESTS_QUERY as its argument.

Answer (score 0):

I think your issue is in quoting.

Try:

```bash
check_deprecating_api() {
    echo "Search for to be soon deprecated API"

    local API_REQUESTS_QUERY='{range .items[?(@.status.removedInRelease=="1.25")]}'
    API_REQUESTS_QUERY+='{.status.removedInRelease}{"\t"}'
    API_REQUESTS_QUERY+='{.status.requestCount}{"\t"}'
    API_REQUESTS_QUERY+='{.metadata.name}{"\n"}{end}'
    echo ${API_REQUESTS_QUERY}
    kubectl get apirequestcounts --output=jsonpath="${API_REQUESTS_QUERY}"
}
```

Using `'` to quote text prohibits shell replacement but it looks better. If you wish to use shell replacement you can use `"` but then need to escape nested `\"`

You can span the JSONPath query over multiple lines to save the repeated `+=`:

```
VERS="1.25"
API_REQUEST_QUERY="
  {range .items[?(@.status.removedInRelease==\"${VERS}\")]}
   ...
  {end}"
```

Or use string|line continuation (`\`):

```
VERS="1.25"
API_REQUEST_QUERY=""\
"{range .items[?(@.status.removedInRelease==\"${VERS}\")]}"\
"..."\
"{end}"
```